# Turning from .cproject to .vcproj

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, gcc, mingw

I have searched a net for some nice code and suddenly I have bumped on a one, however it's been worked in Eclipse, and since I  don't have an Eclipse( and I am not planning to instal it anyway ) I can't properly compile it on my VS10. The thing is that all linker references are mapped in .cproject and if I create an app in my VS10 and paste all the headers and cpp files to it, I still can't build it, 'cause it freezes once it gets up. The main issue may lay in .cproject, so my Q. is can I somehow transform .cproject to .vcproj without much fuss so that this can work on my VS10 as well? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the fuss partially by using CMake (http://www.cmake.org/)

You need to extract the source files' list from the .cproject and run the CMake to get the .vcproj/.vcxproj  (basically, you create the "metaproject" for "all of the IDEs")

If you require some extra compiler setup then the fuss is unavoidable.